# Convert nested list List<List<Object>> into Set<Object>

Tags: java, list, lambda, set, java-stream

I am making a program that converts pictures to a grayscale form and from that grayscale form it converts it to a fairey format.

I am using nested for-loops to convert a nested list. This works perfectly but I want to do it using streams and if I do it using that the output changes, but I think it should result in the same output. Where am I wrong?

grayPhoto is a `List<List<Graypixel>>`

Do any of you see what I'm doing wrong or how the stream should be?

```java
for (int i = 0; i < grayPhoto.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grayPhoto.get(i).size(); j++) {
        numbersSet.add(grayPhoto.get(i).get(j));
    }
}

grayPhoto.forEach(r -> r.forEach(e -> numbersSet.add(e)));
```

Comment: The idiomatic way would be to use flatMap and to collect to a Set, using Collectors.toSet(). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function- Are you asking about an error?

Comment: and what is `numbersSet`? ( I mean why is there such a difference in the name for the same data type.) Apart from which, is it a `List` or a `Set`?

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;) Or comment an answer to get details

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `flatMap` operation, to flatten your list of list to a list (a stream of list to a stream here) then collect as a `Set` :

```
Set<Graypixel> numbersSet = grayPhoto.stream()
                                     .flatMap(List::stream)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

> I think it should result in the same output. Where am I wrong?

You aren’t wrong. Both your ways of converting do result in the same set. I am assuming that `numbersSet` is a `Set<Graypixel>`, for example a `HashSet`.

Even if it was a `List<Graypixel>`, the result would also be the same list in both cases. Of course, if you run *both* snippets, all the pixels will be added twice to the list.

For the canonical way of converting see the comment by JB Nizet or the answer by azro.